# Not able to get all polygons on Interactive Image Map in Js

Tags: html

I'm using an Image of all counties in Texas on webpage using

```html
   <img src="https://txbbw.ml/static/images/jibh.png" width="100%" usemap="#image-map">
          <map name="image-map">
            <area target="" alt="Caldwell" title="Caldwell" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Caldwell/-96.7177005/30.5307282" shape="poly" coords="2146, 2860, 2552, 3200, 2942, 2990, 2483, 2599"/>
            <area target="" alt="Gonzales" title="Gonzales" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Gonzales/-97.4772359/29.5048146" shape="poly"  coords="2946, 2997, 2556, 3213, 2503, 3183, 2202, 3590, 2535, 3920, 3046, 3538, 3098, 3374, 3095, 3262, 3193, 3186" />
            <area target="" alt="Karnes" title="Karnes" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Karnes/-97.915897/28.8880769" shape="poly" coords="2538, 3915, 2337, 4068, 2585, 4327, 2312, 4525, 2291, 4510, 2217, 4506, 2113, 4449, 1992, 4495, 1752, 4231, 2379, 3771" />
            <area target="" alt="Bee" title="Bee" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Bee/-97.7862049/28.409946" shape="poly" coords="2118, 4466, 2217, 4528, 2309, 4538, 2410, 4702, 2466, 4754, 2593, 4745, 2615, 4831, 2700, 4878, 2710, 4866, 2847, 4928, 2600, 5260, 2271, 5196, 1885, 4536" />
            <area target="" alt="SAN PATRICIO" title="SAN PATRICIO" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/SAN PATRICIO/-97.7745336/27.9576203"  shape="poly" coords="2257, 5207, 2149, 5294, 2193, 5382, 2304, 5394, 2278, 5508, 2622, 5612, 2874, 5606, 3098, 5670, 3177, 5576, 3002, 5336, 2875, 5282, 2719, 5235, 2601, 5282" />
            <area target="" alt="Nueces" title="Nueces" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Nueces/-97.6620641/27.7887978"  shape="poly" coords="2239, 5500, 2105, 5612, 2099, 5937, 2184, 5973, 2236, 6049, 2927, 6051, 3033, 5881, 2879, 5841, 2838, 5715, 2521, 5645" />
            <area target="" alt="Kleberg" title="Kleberg" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Kleberg/-97.8969139/27.5028167"  shape="poly" coords="2219, 6064, 2091, 5962, 1925, 5956, 1932, 6457, 2045, 6527, 2815, 6371, 2930, 6058" />
            <area target="" alt="Refugio" title="Refugio" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Refugio/-97.2935169/28.3080144"  shape="poly" coords="2650, 5214, 2874, 4919, 3166, 4693, 3315, 4720, 3492, 4794, 3532, 4779, 3680, 4876, 3657, 4998, 3192, 5090, 3314, 5190, 3053, 5336, 2858, 5233" />
            <area target="" alt="Galveston" title="Galveston" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Galveston/-94.9566483/29.393116" shape="poly"  coords="6105, 3851, 5825, 3435, 5843, 3315, 5914, 3397, 6103, 3320, 6386, 3230, 6403, 3358, 6642, 3385, 6977, 3269, 6999, 3335, 6534, 3509, 6512, 3641"  />
            <area target="" alt="Harris" title="Harris" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Harris/-95.3760728/29.762121" shape="poly" coords="5946, 3366, 6217, 3076, 6228, 2940, 6112, 2829, 6094, 2733, 5999, 2475, 5784, 2663, 5696, 2676, 5471, 2562, 5374, 2484, 5069, 2601, 4826, 2491, 5004, 2981, 5553, 3265, 5762, 3231" />
            <area target="" alt="Sabine" title="Sabine" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Sabine/-93.8547083/31.343520" shape="poly" coords="7457, 1131, 7636, 1099, 8064, 1069, 7812, 452, 7398, 552" />
            <area target="" alt="Newton" title="Newton" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Newton/-93.7616915/30.8510301"  shape="poly" coords="7637, 1107, 8061, 1077, 8181, 1295, 8049, 1778, 7893, 1941, 7877, 2226, 7919, 2353, 7648, 2361, 7702, 1390" />
            <area target="" alt="Jasper" title="Jasper" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Jasper/-94.0266033/30.9249516"  shape="poly" coords="7636, 1106, 6885, 1241, 6895, 1315, 7157, 1263, 7295, 1587, 7353, 1739, 7448, 1815, 7391, 1903, 7361, 2133, 7357, 2360, 7646, 2358, 7696, 1395" />
            <area target="" alt="Orange" title="Orange" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Orange/-93.7478422/30.0918584"  shape="poly" coords="7351, 2364, 7384, 2423, 7355, 2477, 7412, 2523, 7387, 2588, 7473, 2618, 7472, 2649, 7742, 2745, 7976, 2549, 7939, 2364" />
            <area target="" alt="Jefferson" title="Jefferson" href="https://txbbw.ml/map/Jefferson/-94.3525849/32.7622043"   shape="poly" coords="7027, 3221, 7023, 2850, 6904, 2852, 6902, 2543, 7064, 2548, 7137, 2508, 7137, 2464, 7271, 2447, 7345, 2471, 7404, 2534, 7386, 2579, 7481, 2655, 7711, 2736, 7490, 2984, 7298, 3117" />
          </map>
```

I'm able to click on few counties such as Harris, Bee ,etc. but not on other, what might be wrong here?

I'm using https://summerstyle.github.io/summer/ to create polygons

Comment: Can you replace image local path by internet address, so SO users are able to take a look?

Comment: https://txbbw.ml/static/images/jibh.png

Comment: Question: Is it possible using Gimp instead of this services?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnG0nJbAoSM

Comment: Cool, let me check this solution